# How to launch chrome extension tab?

Tags: c#, google-chrome-extension, process.start

I am using c# to open browser with specific urls.
I am trying to open Chrome Extension Tab using this code:

```
Process.Start("chrome", "chrome://extensions");
```

but it doesn't go there.
Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the only [ugly] way is to launch chrome without arguments, wait until its window appears and paste the url into the address bar + Enter key.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't navigate to the privileged URLs (like `chrome:`) this way. I don't think there is a workaround unless you're using an extension (that can do it via `chrome.tabs` API).